# What are reasons why java could "mix up" different instances of the same class?

Tags: java, class

I have code that looks like this:

```
player a=new player(4,10,2,3,"You",'@'); 
player b=new player(4,10,12,3,"Him",'@');   
a.pickUp(new weapon("Lightsaber",true,1,1));
System.out.println(a.getPlayerInventory()[0]); 
System.out.println(b.getPlayerInventory()[0]);
```

However, at this point, the output of this code tells me that the content's of B's inventory also include a lightsaber. (The same object that player A has.)

What are some possible reasons for this to occur in java?  Could it have something to do with whether other methods are static or public/private or not?

I did try googling it, but couldn't find anything (probably because I do not know what this problem is called.)

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Static fields, most likely.

Comment: Do you have the code of the 'player' class at all?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: I wonder why people write `static` when they don't know what it means.

Comment: @Ingo: my experience shows that they start by not making fields and methods static, then they try to use them from the main method, which causes a compilation arror, then find that they can make the fields and methods static to solve the compilation error, and then see static as the magic keyword that allows code to compile :)

Comment: @JBNizet Very likely, yes. That is why I regularly downvote "make it static" recommendations addressed at newbies that struggle with their main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a player's inventory as static, then if A gets a lightsaber, every player will have that same lightsaber

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the implementation of the `player` class I can't say for sure, but the most likely explanation is that the array containing the player's inventory is declared as `static` , which means all instances of the class would share the array.